# Navigation Undefined name Context

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I am currently looking at Navigating withing different screens in my app  and so far I can Navigate from ***LoginScreen*** to ***EventsScreen*** successfully. The problem is in EventsScreen there is a button if clicked it should take me to ***LoginScreen*** and this is the code I have.

in my **events_screen.dart** file
[image]

and in my **app.dart** file ***MaterialApp*** widget I have my routes as
[image]

The *Holiday* flatbutton when clicked it does not take me to the ***"/HolidayScreen"*** route.

How can I solve the **[dart] Undefined name 'context'**?

events_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'holiday.dart';

class EventsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[ 
              Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0)),
              eventsButton(),
              Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0)),
            ],
          ),

        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget eventsButton() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          color: Colors.red[800],
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text(
            'Events',
            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
          ),
        ),



        Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0)),
        FlatButton(
          color: Colors.red[800],
          child: Text(
            'Holidays',
            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/Holiday");
          },       
        ),


        Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0)),
        FlatButton(
          color: Colors.red[800],
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text(
            'Flights',
            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: try 
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("/Holiday");

Comment: change your events_screen.dart to be Stateful , or just pass the buildcontext as parameter

Comment: if you need help, paste the code of your events_screen.dart

Comment: @diegoveloper okay

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Easy, just pass the BuildContext into your `eventsButton` method

```
       Widget build(context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            body: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: ListView(
                children: <Widget>[ 
                  Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0)),
                  eventsButton(context),
                  Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0)),
                ],
              ),

            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```

And add a parameter in your method

```
    Widget eventsButton(BuildContext context) {
      return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment

     //...
```

**UPDATED**

And change this :

```
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/Holiday");
```

To this:

```
   Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/HolidayScreen");
```

Because your route name is HolidayScreen not Holiday

Comment: yeah the error is gone but still cannot navigate to the the HolidayScreen

Comment: it behaves like the **onPressed** method is *null*

Comment: oooh yeah now its working. I have seen what i was missing thanks

Comment: I'm glad to help you :)

Answer (score 5):

Make your method accept your `context` as a parameters

`Widget eventsButton(BuildContext context)`

and call it with the context: `eventsButton(context),`

Comment: yeah the error is gone but still cannot navigate to the the HolidayScreen

Comment: look at your code you are writing the wrong router name 
 `Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/HolidayScreen");` instead of `Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/Holiday");`